# Python euclid's algorithm trying to understand

Tags: python, algorithm

am new to python and I wanted to understand something. how does this work:
(a,b) = (1,2)
because I thought this assigns 1 to a and 2 to b . but when I tryed running euclid's algorithm something different happened and i didnt understand why.

```
  def gcd(n,m):
    while(m>0):
      (n,m) = (m , n % m)
    return n 
  print(gcd(45,126))
```

how is that ^ different from this:

```
def gcd(n,m):
   while(m>0):
      n = m 
      m = n % m
   return n 

print(gcd(45,126))
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Hint: How is `a, b = b, a` different from `a = b; b = a`?

Comment: In tuple expansion, all values on the right-hand side are evaulated *before* assigning on the left hand side. So `n % m` is evaluated before `m` is assigned to `n`.